# Issue with opening XLSX file on Mac OS Big Sur 11.3.1 Excel Version 16.47

Tags: xlsxwriter, python-3.9

I am using python 3.9.5 and am using XlsxWriter1.4.2. I have tried using some basic code to combine CSV files into one single excel file with multiple tabs but am having trouble opening it on the mentioned MacOS and Excel version. I am able to open it on Windows 10.

Here's the code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import xlsxwriter


path = './'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0], index=False)

writer.save()
```

Is there compatibility issues that I'm not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: I am the author of XlsxWriter and I develop it on macOS and test it with Excel 16.50 (as well as several other versions) and there aren't any known compatibility or difference compared to Windows. I also tested your code with some sample CSV files and didn't see any problems. Exactly what issues are you having when you try to open the file?

Comment: Hi @jmcnamara - the file was simply just not opening on my Mac and wouldn't error or anything like that. Silly but I was able to resolve with a simple restart and should have thought of that in the first place. Sorry for the inconvenience but appreciate the help.